# Filtering only unique value from multiple column in R

Tags: r, database, filter

I have data like this:

```
X <- data.frame(fac_1 = c("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y"), fac_2 = c("B", "X", "P", "Q", "C"), fac_3 = c("C", "P", "Q", "T", "U"))

    fac_1 fac_2 fac_3
     A     B     C
     B     X     P
     C     P     Q
     X     Q     T
     Y     C     U
```

I want only those **alphabet** which are common

(1) between fac_1 and fac_2 (like B,C,X) and

(2) all factors which are common among fac_1, fac_2 and fac_3 (like C only)

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @moto I have written in bracket. For example, for case (a) the expected output is B,C, and X

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, craft an example output....

Comment: @Tensibai I think it is very much clear now.

Comment: Did you know that there is a space at `"C "` in `fac_1`?

Comment: Look at `intersect(X$fac_1, X$fac_2)` and `Reduce(intersect, X)`

Comment: @Sotos I corrected it. It was just typos

Comment: @docendodiscimus I have not thought it would be so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `intersect`

```
intersect(intersect(X$fac_1, X$fac_2), X$fac_3)
#[1] "C"
intersect(X$fac_1, X$fac_2)
#[1] "B" "C" "X"
```

Alternatively, the function `Reduce` can be used as described by @docendo discimus at comments section.

```
Reduce(intersect, X)
#[1] "C"
```

Comment: This answer was first provided by @docendodiscimus in the comment. Is it ok if I accept your answer or should I wait till his response ?

Comment: @Neeraj As the answer was provided in the comment by > 1min before this got posted (to avoid any possible lawsuits), it is better to consult the person who commented.

Comment: @Neeraj, I did not see the comment before posting, hence my approach is a bit different at the first case.

Comment: @akrun what is stack exchange policy in such cases?

Comment: @Neeraj I think SO encourage people to post as an answer rather than as comment.  But, it is always good to ask the person who commented first.  Sometimes, the question may not be that clear.

Comment: @akrun I think I can accept the answer given by Sotos, because he provided complete answer.

Comment: I also like the `Reduce` approach more

Comment: @Sotos you can also add this in your answer as an alternative approach.

Comment: I don't mind if you include the reduce approach in your answer since I didn't post an answer myself